# How Can I Get Heroku to Recognize My Application in my Filesystem?

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

I am new to Heroku, and I want to set up my simple Node.js app through Heroku. I have tried following the [Heroku docs for setting up node apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs), and I have done everything it says to do. Unfortunately I have gotten stuck on the [Foreman/Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#declare-process-types-with-foremanprocfile) section. I have created a Procfile like the tutorial says (saved as a .txt file), and have put it in the same directory as my source files. When I try to run Foreman, it says "Error: Procfile doesn't exist". It makes some sense, as Heroku doesn't know where my app directory is, but I want to understand how I can fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not save it as `Procfile.txt` save it only as `Procfile` (dot nothing)